# VS code's auto completing isn't working React JSX code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to autocomplete my code while typing in React JSX code for fister typing But that's not happening. Should I need any additional extensions for that, if yes? any preference for an extension.
If not then what should I suppose to do?

Comment: JSX is more like HTML I don’t understand what you meant by autocomplete there. You can use file association settings to use emmet abbrivations if that is what you ment

Comment: yes I meant abbbriviation.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet